# Problems installing Ubuntu Studio 17.10 in VirtualBox

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, virtualization, 17.10, ubuntu-studio

I've been trying to install Ubuntu Studio 17.10 in Virtualbox 5.2 using both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.10 host machines but to no avail.

When I attempt to install it using the 17.10 ISO it either freezes during the instillation setup, or gives me the 'Errno 5' error message. On one occasion it has just dumped me onto the bash screen and then froze.

When I attempt to install a previous version of Ubuntu Studio and upgrade from there the upgrade seems to work and then when I reboot the virtual machine all I get is a frozen black screen.

I am able to install other Ubuntu 17.10 distros without error, however I am interested in testing how Ubuntu Studio 17.10 is setup and configured (i.e the low latency kernel and the Pulse/Jack integration) and not just the main programs it comes with as I know I can install those easily on other distros.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

A few days after I posted this question I tried downloading a fresh ISO for Ubuntu Studio 17.10 and it installed. This doesn't quite answer why the update from 17.04 wasn't working however.

I assume it was just a corrupt ISO. Hope this helps someone.